# Derivation question

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, self-learning

The function is that

$\pi(p,w_1,w_2)= p f(X_1(p,w_1,w_2), X_2(p,w_1,w_2)) -w_1X_1(p,w_1,w_2)-w_2X_2(p,w_1,w_2)$

Differentiation the profit function with respect to  $w_1$

$\partial \pi/\partial w_1= p \frac{\partial f(X_1(p,w_1,w_2), X_2(p,w_1,w_2))}{\partial w_1}\frac{\partial X_1(p,w_1,w_2)}{\partial w_1 }-w_1 \frac{\partial X_1(p,w_1,w_2)}{\partial w_1}- X_1(p,w_1,w_2)- w_2\frac{\partial X_2(p,w_1,w_2)}{\partial w_1}$

This derivation is true?? If I make a mistake, please let me know in detail.

Please check my derivation.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
{\partial\pi\over\partial w_1}=
p{\partial f\over\partial X_1}{\partial X_1\over\partial w_1}+
p{\partial f\over\partial X_2}{\partial X_2\over\partial w_1}-
w_1{\partial X_1\over\partial w_1}-X_1-w_2{\partial X_2\over\partial w_1}
$$

Comment: I am a bit confused by the notation. Did you drop the constant $p$?

Comment: @Bob Right: I just forgot it, thanks. Corrected now.